# List of custom object in collection (list,array,map etc... ) spring application in JAVA

Tags: java, collections

as per the requirement , i have to create a list of custom objects which holds details like id,name,address in a collection(array,list,map etc..)How to traverse the list of collection in order to fetch the unique records based on the id?

I have created a List Object which holds different collection varity like arraylist,set,map etc...After once the custom object values are assigned to List it is converted to Object class object.For example , i have created a custom object in the form of hashmap with key as 1 and value as custom object of id=1,name=aaa,address=delhi and assigned the custom object to the List and i'm repeating the same process for custom object creation using arraylist and set as well..how to traverse the List object inorder to the user details uniquely based on id?

```
List<Collection> customobjectlist

customobjectlist.add(list)
customobjectlist.add(set)
customobjectlist.add(map)
```

here each list,set and map holds 5 custom objects.I have to traverse the customobjectlist in order to fetch the user details uniquely based on ID?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please less talk, more code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is not a `Collection` in Java, so your code:

```
List<Collection> customobjectlist

customobjectlist.add(list)
customobjectlist.add(set)
customobjectlist.add(map)
```

is not valid if your variable `map` is an instance of a subclass of the `Map` interface.

Second issue, you should type your `Collection` (example: `List<Collection<MyObject>>`), else you'll get `Object` from the collections, you'll have to check `instanceof` every time, it's really not a good thing !

So if you type your `Collection` and add only `Collection<MyObject>` (not `Map`) to `customobjectlist` (`List`, `Set`, `Queue`, `Stack`, `Vector`,...) you have to loop on collections to find your object:

```
for (Collection coll : customobjectlist) {
  for (MyObject obj: coll) {
    if (theIdImLookingFor.equals(obj.getId()) {
      // find it
    }
  }
}
```

It's not the only way to do it, in Java 8+, you can use the stream API :

```
customobjectlist.stream()
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  .findFirst(obj -> theIdImLookingFor.equals(obj.getId()))
```